# How did I accidentally exit edit mode and revert all of my changes?

Tags: shortcut

Twice now I spent a ton of time in edit mode, and upon exiting I noticed it seemed as if my entire scene reverted to my last save. I checked, and there is not a shortcut to "revert" but somehow I am reverting changes when I exit edit mode. Is there some key-combo/shortcut that I must be doing that is causing this?
Thanks!

Comment: One possible thing is that if, after exiting Edit mode, you press `Ctrl`+`Z` to undo (once), you'll undo *all* the changes done in Edit mode (may be handy sometimes). To undo changes done in some mode not globally (not all at once), you should do that from adjacent mode (enter it again).

Comment: That's it! Thanks for answering that. I just tested, and sure enough, that must have been what I did.

Comment: Yes, Blender keeps an "undo book" for every mode, not all together.